# Getting the "To" and "From" fields from a SMTP packet using pyshark

Tags: python, pyshark

How can i get the "To" and "From" categories from a SMTP packet isolated from a stream.

```
import pyshark

fileBuffer = pyshark.FileCapture(pcapDirectory)
samplePacket = fileBuffer[SMTP_Packet_Location]

# Get to and from fields
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
fileBuffer = pyshark.FileCapture(pcapDirectory)
samplePacket = fileBuffer[SMTP_Packet_Location]
print(samplePacket.smtp.get_field_value("req_parameter"))
```

Output:

```
TO: <exampleEmail@provider.com>
```